# overriding the setDefaultCloseOperation

Tags: java, swing, jframe, overriding

I want to customize the close operation of class which extends JFrame. Reading examples of other's code who have done the same thing i find all of them using the WindowListener to implement this. Why cant we do this by overriding the **setDefaultCloseOperation** of the JFrame as:

```
@Override
public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation) {

            super().setDefaultCloseOperation(operation);

            //DO SOME OTHER THING HERE
}
```

Comment: frame is a BIG window it sleeps on listening EDT to proceed further or doing nothing on signal -9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setDefaultCloseOperation` can be called any time and has nothing to do with disposing of the current frame.  It simply changes what will happen when the user tries to close the window by clicking the "close button" on the frame decoration.

`WindowListener` will tell you when a frame is actually been closed or is closing...

Comment: Ok i understand your point....but can't we override the dispose() method instead...why in common practice they choose to use the WindowsListener ...

Comment: `dispose` may or may not be called, depending on the state of the `defaultCloseOperation` and whether `setVisible` was called instead of `dispose`...

Comment: may or may not be called..?......what else can get called when we press the X button on the Jframe ?...can you please explain in a little more detail...

Comment: `WindowListener` ;) ... actually, generally, `setVisible` is called

Comment: One of the reasons NOT to do what you're trying to do, is there are a lot of different types of Windows, a `WindowListener` allows you to modify the way things work, to an extent, without the need to actually modify the existing window, this might occur where you don't actually create the window yourself, but are passed a reference of it...